# How to write code for counting occurrence of specific item(s) in an array?

Tags: java, repeat

[image]

The above is what I've been tasked to create.

Basically, I'm populating an array, and counting the occurrence of **every** element. However, per the instructions, this means that it must be accurate and cannot output the wrong number of occurrences. If you think that's rhetorical, good for you. That's not my issue.

My code:

```
public class CalcOccurrence {

    public static int findIt(int[] list, int i) {
            int[] occurence = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            occurence[i] = list[i];
            boolean hasChecked = false;
            int numberOfTimes = 0;

            for(int j=0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if(j!=9) {
                    if(list[i]==occurence[++j]) {
                        hasChecked=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(hasChecked=false) {
                for(int y = 0; y < list.length; y++) {
                    if(list[i]==list[y]) {
                        numberOfTimes++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return numberOfTimes;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] list = new int[10];
            int[] counter = new int[10];

            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please input an integer between 1 and 100: ");
                list[i] = userInput.nextInt();
            }

            userInput.close();

            for(int n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
                if(list[n]!=0) {
                    counter[n] = findIt(list, n);
                    if(counter[n] > 1) {
                        System.out.println(list[n] + " occurs " + counter[n] + " times.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(list[n] + " occurs " + counter[n] + " time.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I've revised this **twice**, and I still can't rap my head around the right way to approach this. I cannot use any advanced Java tweaks or code that would make it seem that I've cheated or basically ripped it off from the net. I am strictly to only use what I have in my code above.

What I've written above is my attempt to implement this formula of sorts. I thought I could make two arrays in parallel that would keep the number of occurrences in its adjacent index. So, let's say if I typed in 1 for list[0], and there were 4 other occurrences of it. The findIt() method should return a value of 4 which would get assigned to count[0]. This method however, does not work and outputs an inconsistency of occurrence for every instance. It would repeat for each instance is what I mean. So, I invented an array to check if the number had been checked already, but that failed.

I've looked at some previous answers for similar problems, but the code is either too advanced, or I just can't implement it for my purposes.

Comment: Is the between "1 and 100" an actual requirement? Because that would allow for a nice solution.

Comment: If you notice, the sample output has sorted the inputs....*hint

Comment: @Lalaland Yes, it's a requirement unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Your input is composed only by integers in the range between 1 and 100. So you can solve this using a single array to store the counts.

First, create an array that can store 100 elements, one for each possible value:

```
int[] count = new int[100];
```

By default, every position in the array will be initialized with 0.

Now iterate through `list` adding one to the correspondent position for each number you find:

```
for (int number : list) {
    count[number - 1]++;
}
```

We do `number - 1`, so that we store the count for `1` in `count[0]`, for `2`  in `count[1]`, until `100` in `count[99]`.

To print how many times a certain number appeared in `list`, you just need to do:

```
System.out.println(count[number - 1]);
```

Note that your sample output is sorted. This fits nicely with this approach, since we implicitly sorted the input array when we counted the elements. To print the numbers and their counts you can simply do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ": " + count[i]);
}
```

This will print every number from 1 to 100, even those with 0 occurrences. A couple checks should be enough to only print those numbers with 1 or more occurrences and handle the "time" and "times" requirement.

This algorithm is called Counting sort, you can find more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: One note with this type of solution is that it requires a relatively small range of possible inputs. Other solutions (similar to the OP's original attempt) are necessary when the input is not similarly bounded.

Comment: @Lalaland Sure. This is only a good solution because the OP's input is limited.

Comment: Won't this print 0 for any numbers between 0 and 100 which were not in the input?  That should be easy enough to handle with a simple `if (count != 0)` check.

Comment: @Brandon Yes. It was just an example to show that the end result would already be sorted. That's why I also didn't deal with the "time" and "times" requirement. These should be easy for the OP to handle.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I wasn't criticizing the answer, but I think it came across that way.  I was trying to clarify so the OP would be on the same page.

Comment: @Brandon No problem at all. It was good to point that out, so the OP and other users won't get confused =)

Answer (score 2):

This line seems wrong:

```
occurence[i] = list[i];
```

If you are looking for 5, then occurences[5] will be the 6th element of the array, which may or may not be 5.

There are 2 paths forward that I see:

1. Sort the array, then you can iterate over it once, and each time you encounter a number different than the last number, output a counter and reset your counter. Put another way, it's much easier to find that 2 occurs twice in [ 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10 ] than in [ 5, 2, 7, 2, 6, 7, 10 ].
2. Create a map of integer values to occurences: `Map<Integer, Integer>`.  Iterate over your array (sorting does not matter if you do this solution) and for each element, if `map.containsKey(n)` does not map to anything, map it to 1, otherwise, get its corrent value and increment by 1.

**Example of first**

```
int lastElement;
int count = 0;

for (int element : elements) {
    if (element == lastElement) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(element + " occurs " + count + " time(s).");
        count = 0;
        lastElement = element;
    }
}
```

You'll need to figure out how best to handle the initial case of the first iteration, since `lastElement` is uninitialized.  I'll leave that to you.

**Example of second**

```
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> occurences = new TreeMap<>();
for (int element : elements) {
    if (occurences.containsKey(element)) {
        occurences.put(occurences.get(element) + 1);
    }
    else {
        occurences.put(element, 1);
    }
)
```

If it is a requirement that the output be sorted, either of these approaches should work.  I used the `SortedMap` interface to ensure an unordered implementation like `HashMap` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 10000, 500000 };
    System.out.println(countOccurances(input));
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> countOccurances(int[] input) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> ret = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i : input) {
        Integer curr = ret.get(i);
        if (curr == null) {
            ret.put(i, 1);
        } else {
            ret.put(i, ++curr);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Output: `{500000=1, 10000=1, 1=5, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2, 5=1}`

Comment: You can use ret.hasKey()

Comment: @roxan, if you use `hasKey()` and the key is there you have to go get it anyway. No need to query the hashmap twice when once will do.